# Java Image Error

Tags: java, image, int, rgb

Today I got a error that I can't explain I was watching notch's video where he is creating that 2d game the HerpFortress ( http://pt.twitch.tv/notch/b/309642636 (0:42:44) ) , and I was Following his code but on this line I get a error that I get throught...

```
img.getRGB(x * sw, y * sh, sw, sh, result [x][y].pixels, 0, sw);
```

And the error is,

```
The method getRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int) in the type BufferedImage is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
```

help ?

Comment: The 5th parameter should be an array.  You've provided an int in stead. Here's the documentation for [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

Comment: No, it's not.  Otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error.  It looks like you're de-referencing an array to me.

Comment: them the int was on an other class so i didn-t find it thx

Comment: You will need to get used to reading and understanding basic error messages like this if you want to write Java programs.  The error message told you **EXACTLY** what was wrong.  All you have to do is read the error messages!

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself tells you what's wrong.  The [`getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) method expects an array of integers (`int[]`) in the 5th parameter, and you must have supplied a plain `int`, although that's not clear from your code `result [x][y].pixels`.

Answer (score 1):

```
img.getRGB(x * sw, y * sh, sw, sh, result [x][y].pixels, 0, sh);
```

The error in **result [x][y].pixels** :---> this is a value not array, this method in this place take the array in which the data will be written Like this example:

```
int[] outPixels = new int[width*height];
img.getRGB( 0, 0, width, height, outPixels, 0, width );
```

**the Method :**

```
getRGB(startX, startY, w, h, rgbArray, offset, scansize)
```

**Parameters:**

```
startX - the starting X coordinate
startY - the starting Y coordinate 
w - width of region h - height of region 
rgbArray - if not null, the rgb pixels are written here 
offset - offset into the rgbArray scansize - scanline stride for the rgbArray
```